# C++ doesn't give me an output

Tags: c++

I'm trying to loop through a 2d array and find the sum of some numbers but for some reason, I don't get any output from the compilier.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[3][3] = { {2,5,7},
                      {3,6,8},
                      {5,8,6} };

    int oddSum = 0;
    int evenSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            while (arr[i][j] != 2 && arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                evenSum += arr[i][j];
            }

            while (arr[i][j] != 3 && arr[i][j] % 3 == 0)
            {
                oddSum += arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "oddSum = " << oddSum << endl;
    cout << "evenSum = " << evenSum << endl;

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: What are the while loops for? You'll never exit those as soon as the condition is true once. Should be if's

Comment: LEARN TO USE YOUR DEBUGGER!  Step through the code.  Look at the values as you step through.  When you get to the 1st "while" loop, you'll quickly see that the loop condition never changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `arr[i][j]` is not updated within your while loops, if that condition is `true`, it will never be `false` and the loop will never exit.

Comment: _"if that condition is `true`, it will never be `false`"_ - It may, since the whole loop has _undefined behavior_. The compiler is allowed to do whatever it sees fit with it.